# Deploy on docker a net core 2 application

Tags: c#, reactjs, docker, docker-compose, asp.net-core-2.0

When I create a simple React and Net Core 2.2. project with command
`dotnet new react` and add files to build and deploy on Docker the application but docker fail to build.

My Docker Compose File contains:

```
version: '3'
services:
  netreact:
    container_name: netreactapp
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    restart: always
```

And my Dockerfile contains:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:sdk AS base
WORKDIR /app
FROM microsoft/dotnet:sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY *.sln ./
COPY MyReactApp/*.csproj ./MyReactApp/
RUN dotnet restore
WORKDIR /src/MyReactApp
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app /property:PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest=false
FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyReactApp.dll"]
```

So when I run the command to build and up `docker-compose up -d` my docker they fail on Npm restore, with following error:

```
Step 16/22 : RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app /property:PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest=false
 ---> Running in dc0532c03e90
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.0.450+ga8dc7f1d34 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Restore completed in 276.74 ms for /src/MyReactApp/MyReactApp.csproj.
  StWebApp -> /src/MyReactApp/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.2/MyReactApp.dll
  StWebApp -> /src/MyReactApp/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.2/MyReactApp.Views.dll
  /bin/sh: 2: /tmp/tmp813c90672ba947489ab89ec17eb80722.exec.cmd: npm: not found
/src/MyReactApp/MyReactApp.csproj(48,5): error MSB3073: The command "npm install" exited with code 127.
ERROR: Service 'netreactapp' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet publish -c Release -o /app /property:PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest=false' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I think it's because the pipeline of csproj tries to build ClientApp folder using npm, There are any workaround or way to fix it?

Comment: `npm` wasn't found. Either build a custom build image which includes Node, or install Node as a build step before building your project.

Comment: The linked question refers to 2.1 but you can use the same base/build images as your current script, combined with the additions of the linked question.

Comment: @John I don't think, I already tried that.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Same error.... but I`m trying another strategy, building separatelly and it working. So I'm going to put this answer as the one that solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's tutorial on [how to use the React project template with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/react) states that the build process uses npm to restore npm dependencies and to start the server.

Additionally, the same doc states that Node.js is needed to do development builds.

Therefore, you need to ensure that your Docker image will include npm prior to building the application.

Comment: In my dev environment I have both, dotnet and npm installed, works well, my problem is when I automate build and deploy using docker

Comment: It doesn't matter what you have installed in your dev environment.  When you're buildind a Docker image you're setting up a new runtime environment that needs to pack all the required packages to run the applications on any system. This means you need to ensure that the Dockerfile installs every single dependency.  In your example you start with the `microsoft/dotnet:sdk` Docker image, which already includes all the .NET stuff, but you still need to install the remaining dependencies.

Comment: But I can not make it work that way, I think it might be related to the build pipeline present in CSProj, since adding NodeJs in dockerfile, I can not generate the build, would I have a solution?

Comment: @JoãoCota based on the error message you've presented above, the pipeline fails because your Dockerfile does not install npm prior to calling `dotnet publish (...)`.  Therefore, as npm isn't present in your Docker image at that point then that step fails. If you add a couple of steps to install npm and your npm dependencies prior to calling `dotnet publish` then you'll that specific error.

Comment: But is not related with the answer link or explanation.

Comment: @JoãoCota it is.  I suggest you review the build process of a React app, particularly how npm is involved and why npm must be available during the build for the process to succeed, and how your Dockerfile tries to run npm commands when npm hasn't been installed.